# how to assign argc and argv to global variables?

Tags: c

Basically I want to pass main's `argc` and `*argv[]` to global variables, but am getting:

> error: `args` has an incomplete type `char *[]`;

code:

```
int argi;
char *args[];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    argi = argc;
    args = argv;
    // blah bah blah
}

int foo(){
    printf("argv[0]: %s\n", args[0]);
    // ayy what it is.
}
```

Note: for some reason, I don't want to do `foo(int argc, char *argv[])` and then in main calling it as `foo(argc, argv);`

So precisely said, I need to assign main's `argc` and `argv` to my global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays and pointers aren't perfectly equivalent, even though they often appear to be convertible. Use `char **argv` instead of `char *argv[]` (and the same for the global), and this will then work.

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 problem:

1. The `argv` array type is quite restrictive when it comes to managing program parameters.

---

Hence, the best practice is always about using the pointer of the `argv` arguments array without altering its data structure: the `char **argv`.

This way, you can easily transfer or use the array in your source codes.

---

Here is a quick example (tested with `gcc`, `amd64`, on Debian OS) derived from your code snippets:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int argi;
char **args;

int foo(void) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<argi; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, args[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    argi = argc;
    args = argv;
    return foo();
}
```

If you compile and run, you should get the following:

```sh
u0:demo$ ./a.out 
argv[0]: ./a.out

u0:demo$ ./a.out one
argv[0]: ./a.out
argv[1]: one

u0:demo$ ./a.out one two
argv[0]: ./a.out
argv[1]: one
argv[2]: two

u0:demo$ ./a.out one two three
argv[0]: ./a.out
argv[1]: one
argv[2]: two
argv[3]: three

u0:demo$
```

---

***UPDATE***

`Fri Apr 19 16:46:05 +08 2019`:

- removed the "string pointer" problem as it was invalid since the string pointer string pointer is represented by `char *variable`, not `char *variable[]`.